# Overlapping LAS tiles and edge artifacts

Tags: r, lidar, las, lidr

I've read the [Overlapping LAS tiles](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/345919/overlapping-las-tiles) post, but it doesn't pertain to the following situation.

I'm trying to process a las catalog where I clip the catalog at specific plot locations with a 30 m radius.
[image]

As a result of the 30 m radius, the clipped tiles overlap and I see edge artifacts in the output (as indicated might happen in the readLAScatalog warning).
[image]

Is it possible to process these tiles as a catalog without edge artifacts?
Or will I need to read each file individually using readLAS?
I've tried processing the catalog sequentially, but the output still has edge effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your case is covered in the book in this [section](https://jean-romain.github.io/lidRbook/engine.html#engine-independent-files). The idea here is that your files are no longer a wall-to-wall coverage of a territory. The `LAScatalog` engine is designed to process las files that encompass a territory where each files is spatially related to its neighbourhood.

In your case the files are independent. You basically want to loop through each file. In this case you can put this information in the catalog

```r
opt_independent_files(ctg) <- TRUE
```

Each file will be processed independently, without buffer. This is equivalent to a regular loop (but with parallel capabilities and real time monitoring).

In addition depending of what you are doing you may want to avoid final merging

```r
opt_merge(ctg) = FALSE
```

Comment: That's great and thanks for link!

Comment: I edited my answer to show you how to do not merge the output